# enable landscape orientation in only one view on ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{           
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

I just want to enable landscape orientation in only one view of my app. Other view must support the portrait mode only. But for iOS 6 its autorotate even I am using the latest methods of iOS 6. Expecting correct suggestion.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565188/ios-6-landscape-and-portrait-orientation/14704401#14704401

Comment: thanks.. but Used the method in the link still it is supporting orientation. I want portrait orientation except one view that support two landscape and Portrait.

Comment: No its just not working.. I hav tried it earlier.. The main problem is in iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

For **Portrait  Only Orientation**  , try below method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return FALSE;
}
```